# How to map two tables having large database?

Tags: mysql, database

I am doing this in mySQL.
Currently I have two tables: 1. universitiestable 2. coursestable

Table 1. has  list of all universities in the world.
Table 2. has all the courses list.

Universities Table has following columns:

```
id  University_Name 
1   NYU   
2   Yale
3   Oxford
```

Courses table has following Columns:

```
id      Course      Univ_ids
1       BS             1:2
2       MS             3:1
3       Phd            1:2:3
```

now is this the correct approach to store data in this scenario where i need all the courses provided by each university listed in universitiestable

Comment: Universities Table has following columns:
id  University_Name 
1   NYU   
2   Yale
3   Oxford
Courses table has following Columns:
id      Course      Univ_ids
1       BS             1:2
2       MS             3:1
3       Phd            1:2:3

now is this the correct approach to store data in this scenario where i need all the courses provided by each university listed in universitiestable

Comment: Nope - don't concatenate your universities in the courses table.

Comment: Then how to map? Thanks for your help sir.

Comment: 1 row per university per course in the courses table

Comment: What about data redundancy then?

Answer (score 0):

I myself figured out the solution.
I need to create a third table which stores the mappings.
third table will be like this with the following fields table name:university_courses

```
id  course_id  university_id
1    1          2
2    3          3
```